# Why is en-IE culture not giving me AM PM in format string?

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format

I have this code to set the culture

```
        public static CultureInfo GetRegionDefaultCulture(int regionId)
        {   
            // removed code to shorten....
            return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-au");

        }
```

using it here in the code behind in my test example

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
               CultureHelper.GetRegionDefaultCulture(regionId);
```

using this in aspx code behind of my test example

```
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        Response.Write("<br/>" + dtNow.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt"));
```

outputs

```
09 Nov 2010 04:42 PM
```

If I update the code to use any of these cultures, I also correctly get AM/PM in the output

```
en-PH
en-GB
en-US
en-JM
```

If I update the code to use

```
en-IE
```

the output is

```
09 Nov 2010 04:44
```

Am I missing something? Why is en-IE behaving differently?

**Answer**
Gained from @Jordans answer.

Adding this bit of code worked.

```
            DateTimeFormatInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
            info.AMDesignator = "AM";
            info.PMDesignator = "PM";
```

Comment: For the record: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country#Ireland

Comment: Internationalization means not always getting the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator.aspx), if the culture doesn't use AM/PM, then nothing will be returned by `tt`.

> For cultures that do not use an AM designator, this property returns an empty string.

I can't find any documentation on which cultures have an AM designator. The culture info is retrieved via a native method for which I can't find the source. You can generate your own list with the following code:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
  .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator)));
```

Comment: thanks I think this is the answer... if I could find the documentation that confirms which cultures have an AM designator then that would confirm... I've had a bit of a google with no luck so far.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the locale settings for "en-IE" uses a 24-hour clock by default, so there is no need for AM/PM.

Comment: where are you getting that info from?

Comment: That wikipedia link in the comments for the question might be a good resource.  Locale settings are pretty loose.  Whoever implemented them for en-IE is basing them on some set of assumptions around common conventions in a country.  Apparently Irelend tends to use a 24-hour clock more than a 12-hour clock, so that's how this Locale was implemented.

Comment: DateTime.Now gives 24h format with en-GB as well... but the formatting gives me the AM/PM still

Comment: @Rob.Oakshott You could also call `GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT)` and note that it returns `HH:mm:ss` (the capital HH means 24-hour format). Other locales might return `hh:mm:ss tt` (the lowercase hh means 12-hour format, and tt is the placeholder for AM/PM). Windows 7 is configured to not return tt for the `en-GB` locale.

Answer (score 0):

This is a behavior of Culture. It uses windows cultural settings to manipulate its details. if you set locale information as you wish , you should set what are the AM/PM Designators.
That is what you have done by using @Jordans code.

But the problem here is language. 'AM' and 'PM' comes to any locale. but what need to be happened is 'AM' and 'PM' should change according to the locale.

E.G : if your locale information is "zh-TW" result would be 下午 04:16:08.

So Using 24 hour clock is a one solution. but no AM/PM as we know
E.G 3.15 PM = 15:15
this is a one of the good solution because this is a stranded.

Second solution which is offer is this.
changing the locale/cultural setting of the server. 
please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688125.aspx

Hope my comment would help you.